# Using Password Variable in System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory context

Tags: powershell, passwords, system

Does anyone know how to use password in System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory context. Password is stored in a file.

```
$UserName="DomainName.com\JohnP"
$PassFile="C:\Temp\Pass.PPP"
$password = get-content $PassFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$UserName",$password)

$a = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", "MyForest.com",$UserName,$Password)
```

It always returns "Server rejected the credentials". If I store password in $Password variable, it works. For example, below code works:

```
$UserName="DomainName.com\JohnP"
$PassFile="C:\Temp\Pass.PPP"
$password = "MyPassword"

$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$UserName",$password)

$a = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("Forest", "MyForest.com",$UserName,$Password)
```

Can someone please help as to how to use password from a file and then use with System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory context.

Many thanks!
Nratwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `[PSCredential]` stores the password as a secure string, so it's encrypted.

To get the unencrypted password value:

```
$creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!